# ACF multiple image sizes in repeater field

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I want to use the repeater fields to display a block of content and images as a list. However, I don’t want to use one crop size for all images.

For example:

```
List item 1: Image size 1
List item 2: Image size 2
List item 3: Image size 2
List item 4: Image size 3
```

Is this even possible?

The markup I am currently using is:

```
<ul>

<?php while( have_rows('home-features') ): the_row(); 

    // vars
    $image = get_sub_field('image');
    $description = get_sub_field('description');
    $url = get_sub_field('url');

    ?>

    <li>

        <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">
            <div>
                <h3><?php echo $description; ?></h3>
            </div>
        </a>

    </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Just create a variable you can use to keep count of the image then increment it inside the `while` loop, then use that variable to decide the image size you want. Something like: https://pastebin.com/uBqz0MjE

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to assign a specific image size to each repeater element, why not just add another ACF sub-field in the repeater with a select for the image sizes?

Your new "Image Size" (`image_size`) Select sub-field Choices could go something like this:

```
thumbnail : Thumbnail
medium : Medium
medium_large : Medium Large
large : Large
full : Full Size
```

You can substitute your own custom image sizes if you want above, as long as the value of each select item corresponds to the custom image size `$name` value ([see codex for reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)).

Then in your loop:

```
<ul>

  <?php while( have_rows('home-features') ): the_row(); 

  // make sure the ACF return format is set to 'image array' on the image field
  $image = get_sub_field('image'); 

  // new select field described above
  $size = get_sub_field('image_size'); 

  // put the two together using the image array values
  $img_url = $image['sizes'][ $size ];

  $description = get_sub_field('description');
  $url = get_sub_field('url');

  ?>

  <li>

    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">
      <div>
        <img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>">
        <h3><?php echo $description; ?></h3>
      </div>
    </a>

  </li>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
```

**References**

1. [add_image_size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)
2. [Post Thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)
3. [ACF Image Field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)

**Note:**
I haven't tested this code so let me know if you have any trouble!